# 'He told her that he loved only her.' vs 'He told her that he loved her only.'

Tags: differences

Neil Guthrie [DPhil English (Oxon), LLB (Toronto)](https://www.linkedin.com/in/guthrieneil/).  [*Guthrie’s Guide to Better Legal Writing*  (2017)](https://www.amazon.ca/Guthries-Guide-Better-Legal-Writing/dp/1552214729).

p. 65

> [image]

Question 1. How does 6 differ from 7?

Question 2. [Joanna Weselby](https://magpiecws.wordpress.com/tag/english/) [(BA (Hons), English Literature and Creative Writing, Nottingham Trent University)](https://magpiecws.wordpress.com/about/) thinks that they:

> are perhaps the most similar, as they express largely similar sentiments, but even here, the implication of the latter **is of an earlier time; a different manner of speaking [I bolded.]**.

But how is the bolded phrases true for 7?

Comment: Aren't the 2nd and 3rd the same too?

Comment: @DXV - Nope. 2 means that she's the only one that he told, 3 means it's the only thing that he told her.

Answer (score 1):

I would interpret the two sentences as follows:

> 6. He told her that he loved **only** her.

He told her that there is nobody else whom he loves.

> 7. He told her that he loved her **only**.

He told her that the only thing he feels for her is love.

---

I would actually say that 5. is ambiguous:

> 5. He told her that he **only** loved her.

I could interpret this as having the same meaning as either 6. or 7.

---

I disagree with Joanna Weselby, as I see a distinct difference between 6. and 7.

Comment: Both 5 and 7 are ambiguous, depending on where the stress is when said. "He told her that he only loved *her*" means the same as "He told her that he loved only *her*" = same as 6. "He told her that he only *loved* her" means the same as "He told her that he *loved* her only" means that the only thing he feels for her is love.

Comment: Actually, adding to my previous comment, you can change the meaning of 7 again with yet another stress: "He told her that *he* loved her only" which has the same meaning as 4. Stress on *he* doesn't change the meaning for 5 though.

Comment: @andyt The stress should be explicit in each case—it's on **only**. Otherwise, you're right.